# Javascript not executing into a page using Selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My Javascript isn't executing into my page(s) using Selenium.

My code:

```
    // Create a driver instance for chromedriver
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

            driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1100, 1100);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
            js.ExecuteScript("function reloadScrollBars() { document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'auto';  document.body.scroll = 'yes';} function unloadScrollBars(){ document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden'; document.body.scroll = 'no';}");
```

Could anybody share any knowledge as to why it's not executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked

```
js.ExecuteScript("return document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';");
```